# Struts2 template for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, struts2

I am starting to learn Struts2 and am looking for  a plugin for Eclipse IDE for rapidly setting up Struts2 Projects.

Could the community advise me on available options for rapid Struts2 development in Eclipse?
Please share any links if you feel they can assist me.

Answer (score 1):

You would use maven2 to create a template project (archetype) and then use maven eclipse plugin to convert it to eclipse project then importing it from eclipse

Answer (score 0):

As has been suggested already here I would advise you to use [Maven](http://apache.maven.org) for creating archetypes, but also because Maven will offer you abstraction from your IDE (meaning that if you don't like what Eclipse has to offer, just ditch it for any other modern IDE and you project should be ready to be used in (hopefully) in that newer IDE.